# how to properly destroy c++ classes with smart pointers

Tags: c++, destructor, smart-pointers

I know basically delete is only required when I allocate something using new. However, I'm not certain about how to deallocate smart pointers and those classes which contain smart pointers as their members. So, how can I properly implement the destructors in the following classes?

```
template <typename T>
class Array {
public: 
    Array(const unsigned int length){
        T* ptr = (T*)malloc(sizeof(T)*length);
        array = std::shared_ptr<T>(
            new(ptr) T[length], 
            [](T* ptr){free(ptr);}
        );
    }
    ~Array(){
        // Q1 how should I properly implement this destructor?
    }

private:
    std::shared_ptr<T> array;
};

class Example{
public:
    Example(){
        ...
    }
    ~Example(){
        // Q2 how should I properly implement this destructor?
    }
private:
    Array<float> bufferFloatArray;
    Array<float>* bufferFloatArrayPtr;
    std::shared_ptr<float> bufferFloatPtr;
}
```

Comment: Q1) the shared_ptr destructor is automatically called when ~Array() is called. Nothing special to do
Q2) Nothing to do for bufferFloatArray and bufferFloatPtr. For bufferFloatArrayPtr, it depends on what this pointer points to. Something allocated with `new` in `Example` constructor?

Comment: I would like to know what will you do if you don't know what bufferFloatArrayPtr points to. Maybe it is not created inside Example class?

Comment: It may be helpful: https://www.acodersjourney.com/top-10-dumb-mistakes-avoid-c-11-smart-pointers/

Comment: Well there is nothing you can do if you don't know what bufferFloatArrayPtr points to. Sometimes a raw pointer points to an object which is constructed and destructed by an other entity. Sometimes it's created by an entity and destructed by an other (which is called transferring of ownership). C++ gives you full freedom on how objects life cycles and memory is managed. It's you job to design something that works.

Comment: Your deleter is incorrect BTW, you don't delete the T from placement new.

Comment: placement new for array cannot really be done, as extra space might be required, and we don't know how much space (implementation specific and no getter) :-(

Comment: Thanks to all you guys. In fact, the Array class is only meant to wrap a CUDA array of type int, float or float3, not for other objects. Therefore the malloc is actually cudaMalloc, so I have to use cudaFree rather than delete or destory_n.

Answer (score 2):

Smart pointers automatically invoke their destructors. So you don't need to implement `~Array()`, however in class Example you use raw pointer `(Array<float>* bufferFloatArrayPtr)`, which should be properly deallocated in `~Example()`.

PS Note that you made an error in class Array implementation. Use `delete[] ptr` instead of `free(ptr)` in `shared_ptr` *delete-expression* to avoid memory leak.

Comment: That isn't an error in the `Array` class. That memory is allocated with `malloc`, and therefore should be `free`d (which it is in the custom deleter). A *potential* error is using any non-trivial type for T. The OPs code will work for `Array<float>`, but fail miserably for `Array<std::string>`, for example.

Comment: `new(ptr) T[length]` is the placement-new syntax. `free(ptr)` is correct. The real problem is the missing destructor call.

Comment: Guys, thanks for your comments. Actually, my remark was about initial version of the post, which had this leak.

Comment: @gimme_danger Well, the edit happened 14 minutes before you post the answer ... You should include this information in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

> **Note: The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56272077) by [@gimme_danger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11517034) refers to an [old version](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/56271700/1) of the question. Here's the answer for the [new version](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/56271700/2).**

---

The

```
T* ptr = (T*)malloc(sizeof(T)*length);
array = std::shared_ptr<T>(
    new(ptr) T[length], 
    [](T* ptr){ /*...*/ }
);
```

You first allocate some memory using `malloc`, then use the placement-new syntax to call the constructor of `T`. You need to do both in the deleter.

```
[](T* ptr) {
    std::destroy_n(ptr, length);
    std::free(ptr);
}
```

You don't need a destructor. The destructor of `shared_ptr` is destroyed automatically. By the way, your class has pointer semantics, i.e., two instances may share the same memory, which is probably not desired.